# Why does MSVC not auto-generate code for an explicitly-defaulted, noexcept default constructor used to copy construct a designated initializer?

Tags: c++, c++20, default-constructor, noexcept, designated-initializer

See this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n34cK41Y9):

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() noexcept = default;
    int t{};
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo baz{};
};

int main()
{
    return Bar
    {
        .baz = Foo{}
    }.baz.t;
}
```

When deleting `noexcept`, code for the constructor is auto-generated as expected. What gives?

Comment: What do you mean with "_auto-generated_"? What specifically in the godbolt link do you consider unexpected?

Comment: The above program won't link because the called symbol `Foo::Foo(void)` is missing! When deleting `noexcept`, the program successfully links because the compiler generates code for Foo's constructor.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't notice that. Looks like a bug in MSVC to me.

Comment: I thought I might have missed something with the noexcept, but I think so too. Thanks for having a look! I will report to Microsoft.

Comment: My guess would be it'll only generate the constructor when it is actually used and the compiler doesn't realise that it is being used in the initialiser